# How do I return the next follow on record based on dates in a SQL Server query?

Tags: sql, sql-server

As part of my vessel hire database I have a view that returns a selection of information about the vessels we have and also their fixture commitments.  In our system, any vessel on fixture has that commitment flagged as "Live" and any fixture commitment for that vessel which comes AFTER the offhire date will be flagged as "FollowOn" (The live and follow on flagging is performed by the user on the front end).

***The problem***

A vessel can have multiple FollowOn commitments and so I need to find a way to return only the next commitment flagged as FollowOn after the offhire date of the current Live commitment.

***The Query (So far)***

```
SELECT        

uve.[Id], 
uve.[ViewId], 
uve.[VesselId], 
ve.[Name],

/***********************  
    #Fixture (Current)
***********************/ 
CAST((CASE WHEN fix1.[Id] IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE fix1.[Id] END) AS INT) AS [FixtureId], 
fix1.[Date], 
fix1.[FirmUntil], 
fix1.[Charterer],
ch1.[ChartererName],

/***********************  
    #Fixture (Next)
***********************/ 
fix2.FollowOn,
fix2.Id AS NextFixtureId, 
fix2.[Date] AS NextOnhire,
CAST((CASE WHEN fix2.FollowOn IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE fix2.FollowOn END) AS BIT) AS FollowOn, 
fix2.[FirmUntil] AS NextOffhire, 
ch2.ChartererName AS NextChartererName,
CAST((CASE WHEN fix1.[Live] IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE fix1.[Live] END) AS BIT) AS Live

FROM UserVessels AS uve 
LEFT JOIN Vessel AS ve ON ve.Id = uve.VesselId 
LEFT JOIN VesselTypes AS vt ON vt.[Id] = ve.[Type] 

LEFT JOIN (SELECT  [Id], [Date], [FirmUntil], [PeriodAmount], [PeriodFrequency], [Charterer], [Port], [Live],[FollowOn], [Broker], [WorkRole], [VesselId]
            FROM Fixture
            WHERE Live = '1' AND FollowOn = '0') AS fix1 ON fix1.[VesselId] = ve.Id

LEFT JOIN (SELECT [Id],[Date],[Live],[FirmUntil],[FollowOn], [Charterer], [Port], [WorkRole], [VesselId]
            FROM Fixture AS f2
            WHERE f2.[FollowOn] = '1') AS fix2 on fix2.[VesselId] = ve.Id
            

LEFT JOIN Charterer AS ch1 ON ch1.Id = fix1.Charterer 
LEFT JOIN Charterer AS ch2 ON ch2.Id = fix2.Charterer
```

As you can see, the heavy lifting for what I'm trying to achieve happens in the join where I have a subquery looking at the FollowOn flag.  This isn't ideal because if there is more than one fixture with followon then you get lots of rows.  I need only the immediate next followon after the offhire of "fix1" so that I can keep each vessel as a single row and was wondering how that can be achieved?

Comment: This is a "top 1 per group" problem, you can either use `row_number` or `outer apply`, there are hundreds of examples

Comment: @Yanayaya . . . Your question is *much* simpler than your query.  I would suggest that you ask a question with sample data and desired results -- so it is easier to understand the question.   The actual query that generates the results is not really needed.  However, knowing what results you want is needed, and the question doesn't clearly explain that.

Answer (score 0):

So if you've got a list of all of the follow on fixtures, as alluded to in the comments you can use a row_number window function to get the next one:

```
LEFT JOIN (SELECT [Id],[Date],[Live],[FirmUntil],[FollowOn], [Charterer], [Port], [WorkRole], [VesselId], ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY VesselId ORDER BY Date) [RNum]
            FROM Fixture AS f2
            WHERE f2.[FollowOn] = '1') AS fix2 on fix2.[VesselId] = ve.Id AND fix2.RNum = 1
```

However the outer apply might be quicker. You'd need to test it.